# Is apple to be grated a wet or dry ingredient?

Tags: baking

Can you please answer this. Is apple a wet or dry ingredient? It will be grated

Comment: Welcome! Could you give us some additional information about the recipe you're using? Maybe post the entire recipe?

Answer (score 3):

Apple is pretty wet.

However, if you're looking at quickbread or muffin recipes (with "wet" and "dry" teams, [*a la* Alton Brown's method](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season7/muffin/muffintrans.htm)), you're better off treating it as a separate addition -- stir the grated apple in after the wet and dry are combined.

Answer (score 2):

Wet. You'll notice how much apple juice you end up with when you try to grate an apple.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, a grated apple is literally wet, but this has little to do with what "type of ingredient" it is. Kitchen tradition just uses confusing names for the ingredients which go into the two different piles of a two-step method. Dry ingredients don't have to be literally dry, and wet ingredients don't have to be literally wet.

I find Erica's approach best, it doesn't belong to neither the dry nor the wet ingredients, and it will be best to add it later to the batter, after dry and wet are mixed.

But if you are insisting on a two-step method, I'd say it's a "dry" ingredient, that is, an ingredient which gets mixed in the "flour" bowl and not the "egg" bowl. The reason: fruit pieces sink to the bottom of a quickbread, and flouring them reduces this problem. So throwing the apple pieces into the flour will ensure a more even distribution. Just make sure that they don't land on top of the baking powder before you start mixing.

Making them a wet ingredient not only means you miss the opportunity to get them floured, but they will also interfere with foaming the wet ingredients. While quickbreads with grated apples with them are expected to be coarser than cakes made with a more elaborate method than a simple dry+wet mixing, you still want all the air bubbles you can get without sacrificing convenience, so there is no need to reduce them by mixing the apple with the eggs and sugar.

Comment: To add to this, I even have a carrot cake recipe that specifically tells you to add the grated carrot to the dry ingredients to coat them, then add the wet ingredients after.